# File not found exception when trying to get drag and drop image in java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

My code as follows

```
<script>
    var formData = new FormData();
        var doc = document.documentElement;
        var files;
        doc.ondragover = function () {
            this.className = 'hover';
            document.getElementById("image-div").style.border = "dotted";
            return false;
        };
        doc.ondragend = function () {
            document.getElementById("image-div").style.border = "solid";
            this.className = '';
            return false;
        };
    doc.ondrop = function (event) {
        document.getElementById("image-div").style.border = "solid";
        event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
        this.className = '';
        files = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append('file', files[i]);
        }
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function (event)
        {
            document.getElementById("previewImg").src = event.target.result;
        }
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(files);
        return false;
    };

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'URL',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
</script>

<body>
    <form class="box" method="post" action="URL" id='SubmitForm' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="image" style="border-style: solid;border-color: yellow;height: 300px;width: 300px;text-align: center;margin: 10px" id="image-div">
            <p><label for="file"><strong>Choose a file</strong></label><span class="hide" id="drag"> or drag it here</span>.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="previewImage" style="display:none;border:1px solid black">
            <img src="#" id="previewImg" style="width:250px;height:auto">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type='file' class="inputfile" name='file' id="file"    accept='image/*' />
            <input type='submit' value='Upload' name='Upload image' />
        </div> 
    </form>
</body>
```

Exception at this line

```
InputStream fileContent = formFile.getInputStream();
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
    C:\Windows\TEMP\upload_723aa03a_1e6b_457a_b020_b33fc078881b_00000001.tmp
    (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Comment: I think that to help you we'd need a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, as stated in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @DM Edited my question... Hope it helps u to provide a solution.
I think there is a problem in sending the drag and drop image to server